# State after mremap Failure

Tags: linux, mmap

When `mremap` fails, is the old mapping still valid and usable? I `mmap` a file similar to a database in that it has blocks of data and free lists. When I run out of blocks, I need to grow the file. At this point I do this by calling `ftruncate` with the new size, then `mremap` to remap the entire file with the additional space. I have not been able to find out what happens if `mremap` fails and don't have a particularly good way to test on the embedded platform where this is running.

Note I am using the flag `MREMAP_MAYMOVE` and am not specifying a new address.

I apologize if this has an answer somewhere, but I sure can't seem to find it in any man pages or other documentation online.